# Set UISearchBar Background Color to White

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am facing issue to set bg color of UISearchBar as White. I have tried to set bg as white but still default gray bg color is there.
I tried this code.

```
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I dont understand what's wrong. Bcz when i set any color like green or red, they are set easily.
Please provide answer in Swift 4+ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't set background color of SearchBar as white.

As we can see all Apple default Apps doesn't have white BG color,

Solution: **We need to make customised SearchBar for that.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below in Appdelegate

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = . white
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't making white bg

Comment: Actually i want white bg at place where we enter text as input.